# Changing a user control inside property outside it

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a simple user control with a Ellipse and a TextBlock

I want to change the TextBlock.Text property inside the User Control from outside like this

I didnt find any simple explanation or way to do this

if there's any i would like to know

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose it as a property:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return MyTextBox.Text; }
        set { MyTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

If you want to set it via a binding, then you need to create a dependency property, but if you're just using literals and/or code-behind, then the above is fine.